# Using sys.intern(string) and NewType from typing module together in Python?

Tags: python, string, memory, typing, sys

How does one use [sys.intern(*string*)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sys.html#sys.intern) and [NewType](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#newtype) together?

```
import sys
from typing import NewType

UserName = NewType('UserName', str)

username = UserName(sys.intern('awesome_repeated_name'))
# or
username = sys.intern(UserName('awesome_repeated_name'))
```

And is the purpose of using `sys.intern()` achieved, ie string being stored only once in memory each time it shows up when using `NewType` as such?

Comment: Why are you using `sys.intern` here??

Comment: the same string (in this case user name) may repeat itself in other locations, idea being to have a unique memory allocation. But I may be wrong about how to use it properly?